# Laravel 5.6 Route Model Binding Behaving Weirdly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

This is a really strange problem because I've never had any issues with route model binding before. I have a resource route:

```
Route::resource('metadata','MetadataController');
```

I have a redirect in the index method of my `MetadataController` that gets fired when someone clicks on a link.

```
return redirect()->route('metadata.edit', 1);
```

In my `RouteServiceProvider.php` file I have the following:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('metadata', \App\Models\Metadata::class);
    Route::model('settings', \App\Models\Settings::class);
}
```

Note that I have an identical setup for my settings Route/Controller and it works fine.

In my edit method I have the following:

```
public function edit(Metadata $metadata)
{
    dd($metadata); // Never reaches here
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this route isn't binding properly? (or at all)

Additional notes:

If I remove the route binding from the `RouteServiceProvider` and the type casting to `Metadata` in the `edit` method, it does call the `edit` method.

Both of these lines work just fine:

```
 Route::model('settings', \App\Models\Settings::class);
 Route::model('settings', App\Models\Settings::class);
```

This line doesn't throw an error but gives me a page not found message:

```
 Route::model('metadata', \App\Models\Metadata::class);
```

This line throws an error:

```
 Route::model('metadata', App\Models\Metadata::class);
```

`Class App\Providers\App\Models\Metadata does not exist`

Seems like there's a bit of weirdness going on and I am not sure what it is, thoughts?

Comment: One of your service providers in `App\Providers` folder doesn't use correct namespace for Metadata. Check them and add "\" in front of `App\Models\Metadata` where it's missing.

Comment: You will have to use the "\" before the `App\Models\Metadata::class` as the RouteServiceProvider is in the `\App\Providers\` namespace. Do you have debugbar installed? If so you can check the query.